# Correct usage of "ago" and "back."

Tags: grammaticality

Which expression is more apt?
"I met him a few days back."
Or the following, "I met him a few days ago"?

Comment: More apt to what? Also, the title of the question asks about *before*, but the text of the question asks about *back*. Please edit your question to clarify and provide sufficient context. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. I'd say it's merely a question of formality and idiom, "back" being more colloquial and "ago" being more formal.